# ConnectionString with spectific AD account credential

Tags: c#, sql-server, active-directory

I host a windows service running under a specific AD user account. This user has no right in my MS SQL database. Instead of that, I have another AD user account that has rights in my database, but can't run a windows service.

Here is my following connection string :

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="CnxDev" connectionString="Server=FOOOOO1111\DEV2008R2;Database=Fooo;Trusted_Connection=True;"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

How can I specify specific AD user credential to consume my SQL requests ?
Of course I already check on the internet to find any information, but nothing related to windows service and AD account in an AD account.

Comment: A trusted connection uses a Windows login as the credentials.  So the local PC and remote PC has to be in the same group to share users credentials.  The Credentials in the database has to specify the windows credentials.  Usually a single Windows Group Account is created and the database references the Windows Group.  Then users are added to the windows group so the database credentials doesn't have to change every time a new user is added..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider setting up a managed service account that has the access you need to both run the service and proper permissions in SQL.  If you do not want to do this (or cant), you can do this with impersonation.  Here is an example using c#

https://platinumdogs.me/2008/10/30/net-c-impersonation-with-network-credentials/

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will try to have an account with both access first. Have a good day.